# Get line which contains string

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a line from a textfile that contains a certain sequence of characters :

my input :

```
    <tr><td>lucas.vlan77.be</td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> </tr>
<tr><td>jeanpierre.vlan77.be</td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span title="Cannot connect to 193.191.187.25:22345." style="color:red;font-weight:bold">X</span></td> <td><span title="No response from DNS at 193.191.187.25." style="color:red;font-weight:bold">X</span></td> </tr>
<tr><td>sofie.vlan77.be</td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span title="Cannot connect to 193.191.187.26:22345." style="color:red;font-weight:bold">X</span></td> <td><span title="No response from DNS at 193.191.187.26." style="color:red;font-weight:bold">X</span></td> </tr>
<tr><td>thomas.vlan77.be</td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> </tr>
```

Now I need to get the line that contains lucas, I tried this with beautifulsoup, but it is not meant to get a line only content of html tags, so I tried with a regular in operator :

```
def soupParserToTable(self,input):
    global header

    soup = self.BeautifulSoup(input)
    header = soup.first('tr')
    tableInput='0'

    for line in input:
        if 'lucas' in line:
            tableInput = line
    print tableInput
```

However it keeps returning 0 instead of

```
<tr><td>lucas.vlan77.be</td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> <td><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">V</span></td> </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `input` is just a string, then `for line in input` doesn't iterate lines, it iterates characters. So `'lucas'` would never be found in a one-character string and `tableInput` would not be assigned. The line-based iteration behaviour only happens when the object is a file.

If you wanted to loop through each line of a string you'd have to do:

```
for line in input.split('\n'):
    ...
```

Since you have BeautifulSoup available I'd say it would be *much* better to use that to read the value from the first cell in each row, rather than rely on crude and fragile string-searching.

ETA:

> how I would get the table entry for the row that contains the string 'lucas' any hints ?

Use `td.parent` to get the containing row, `td.parent.parent` to get the containing table/tbody, and so on.

If you wanted to get the `V` or `X` in the next column, you could say something like:

```
tr= soup.find(text= re.compile('lucas')).parent.parent
vorx= tr.findAll('td')[1].find('span').string
```

Comment: thanks, I've narrowed it down just the td tags now in beautifulsoup, but I can't figure out how I would get the table entry for the row that contains the string 'lucas' any hints ? ^^